# Changing form data attribute via Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change a form data attribute, when the user enters something in the Email form field.

Anyone can give me pointers on why isn't this working?

```
 $('form').change(function() {
        var userEmail = $(this).find('input[name=Email]').val();
        $("#form220180305").data('success-url', userEmail);
 });
```

Comment: Are you able to post your HTML as well to see the main issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the change event is on the Email form field, when the user enters something on it.
use the input keyup event. and for the attribute, use attr instead. see below code:

```
$('input[name=Email]').keyup(function() {
        let userEmail = $(this).val();
        $("#form220180305").attr('success-url', userEmail);
 });
```